# Configuration for grails-redis plugin

Tags: grails, caching, configuration, redis

I'm attempting to use the grails-redis plugin so that I can implement a distributed object cache. I've got both cache and cache-redis in my BuildConfig:

```
compile ':cache:1.1.8'
compile ":cache-redis:1.1.0"
```

And I have redis running locally. I know it is working because if I kill redis, the grails app can't connect to it. What I'm not finding is how to modify the configuration for redis when I'm not running locally.

There is nothing in the [docs here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache-redis/). I also looked through the [source here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-cache-redis) and found nothing of note.

How do I configure the redis settings (host, port, timeout, etc) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at the [CacheRedisGrailsPlugin.groovy](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-cache-redis/blob/master/CacheRedisGrailsPlugin.groovy) for the plugin itself. You will see that redis itself is configured in the `doWithSpring` phase of the plugin setup and reads from the `redisCacheConfig` configuration file for such things as host, port, etc.

Thus, adding something like the following to your Config.groovy would be perfectly acceptable:

```
grails {
  cache {
    redis {
      hostName = 'localhost'
      port = 6379
      timeout = 2000
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I added that to my Config.groovy and gave a bogus hostName and it still connects just fine, so I don't believe this is accurate. Also, it seems odd that : are used instead of = (I tried both, BTW).

Comment: Ok, got it

grails {
  cache {
    redis {
      timeout = 2000 //default in milliseconds
      port = 6379
      hostName = "localhost"
    }
  }
}

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this.